# The left-multiplication transformation $L_A$ is the zero linear transformation if and only if $A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

The left-multiplication transformation $L_A$ is the zero linear transformation if and only if $A=0$

**Attempt:**

If $A$ is the zero matrix, $A=0$, then.

\begin{align*}
0=0v=Av=L_A(v)
\end{align*}

for all $v\in F^n$.

Comment: you only did one of the two implications as far as I can tell.

Comment: You would also have to show that if $L_A= 0$ this implies $A=0$. For that you could use that $L_A(e_i) =0$ for all $i =1, \dots, n$ where $e_i$ is the unit vector with a $1$ at the $i$-th position and zeros everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $A$ is not the zero matrix, then it has a non-zero column $c$, assume it is the $i$'th column.

Let $v$ be the column vector which has $0$ in every entry except for the $i$'th entry which is $1$.

Notice $Av = c$.